# how to create an editable components for GEF Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gef

I want to create a component kind of Text Box for GEF Eclipse.
I am able to create component but not able to make it editable. How to achieve the desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GEF there is direct edit mechanism that can be used for these for these kind of purposes.

When you double click the editpart, it should create [direct edit request](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/gef/tools/SelectEditPartTracker.html). I believe this request is then by default send to the request to EditParts editpolicies.

So you should probably install this [direct edit editpolicy](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/gef/editpolicies/DirectEditPolicy.html)  and that returns [cell editor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/gef/tools/SelectEditPartTracker.html).

It might be that actually installing the direct edit editpolicy provides you the text editor when double clicked, and all of this parts can be modified if the outlook of default implementation is not good.

I checked that it seems that there isn't easy examples about the subject, but there was some talks that "logical" example contains direct edit support.